# How to validate input to slug field with many=True?

Tags: validation, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer for model (an artist) which links to several instance of other model (albums) with a slug field. In serialized form, I want this relationship to be captured as a list of strings (i.e. the artist has a list of album names).

```py
class ArtistSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    albums = SlugRelatedField(slug_field='name',
                              many=True,
                              queryset=Albums.objects.all())
```

The problem with this code is that if the user sends incorrect data that is not a list, they will get a useless error message.

For input `{"albums": "The Best Of"}` the error message will be something like `{"albums": ["Object with name=T does not exist."]}`. It is technically correct, but does not tell the user what the problem is. I would like to return an error message saying that the value for key `albums` must be a list.

*What is the proper way to achieve this?*

---

So far, I have been able to get it to work, but it is not a very nice solution. I subclassed `ManyRelatedField` to raise `ValidationError` when the input is not a list. This class is then used in `many_init` of `AlbumsField`, which is a subclass of `SlugRelatedField`.

```py
class StrictManyRelatedField(serializers.ManyRelatedField):
    def get_value(self, data):
        res = super(StrictManyRelatedField, self).get_value(data)
        if not isinstance(res, list):
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                {self.field_name: ['Expected a list.']}
            )
        return res


class AlbumsField(serializers.SlugRelatedField):
    @classmethod
    def many_init(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        child_relation = cls(**kwargs)
        return StrictManyRelatedField(*args, child_relation=child_relation)
```